# Upsert using multiple key search

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, php-mongodb

I have the following mongodb structure

```
{
    "_id" : 18536,
    "billing" : {
        "patientinfo" : {                        
                "patient_id" : "120196"                        
        },
        "billinginfo" : {
                "billingid" : "B1"                       
        },
        "receiptinfo" : [ ]
    }
}
```

I want to insert array `("receipt_id"=>"R1")` in `receiptinfo` Once one value is inserted again I have to insert another one eg: `("receipt_id"=>"R2")`.
I have tried the following code which is not working:

```
$updatereceipt =$collection->update(
    array('_id' => (int)$id,'billing.receiptinfo.receipt_id'=>$receiptid),
    array('$set' => array('billing.receiptinfo'=>array('receipt_id' => $receiptid))),           
    array("upsert"=>true)
);
```

Comment: Your structure shows that "receiptinfo" is a JSON array but you're using it like a JSON object.

Comment: How can I use it like an json array

Comment: Try something like `array('_id' => (int)$id, 'billing.receiptinfo' => array($receiptid) )` (and similarly for the others). You may also need to get the old value and append to it (not sure if there's a different way to do that)